# A playbook layout style in CSS

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to have a playbook layout style, which goes like this:

```
       Name: Text starting here - style #1
             text which should go in a new line with different style #2
             text continue here with another new line - style #1

Longer Name: Text starting here - style #1
             text which should go in a new line with different style #2
             text continue here with another new line - style #1
```

My problem is i'm unable to get style #2 text start with a new line.

This is my code:

```
<div class="line">
  <div class="level1">
    <div class="name" >name:</div> 
      Text starting here - style #1 
      <span>text which should go in a new line with different style #2</span> 
      text continue here with another new line - style #1
    </div>
  </div>

<style type="text/css">
.line {
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 477px;
    margin: 0 auto;


}

.level1 {
    display: inline-flex;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 12px;


}

.name {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 40px;
    min-width: 50px;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 15px;


}

</style>
```

With these values, Style #2 always being break into a new column and not a new line. Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/edw14jt7/) example. I'm pretty sure this is the "flex-inline" causing it. Do I have any alternative for that?

Comment: does it have to be a span ?

Comment: not at all, it can be any tag that I can apply a specific style to it.

Answer (score 0):

This code may help you.

```
<div class="line">
  <div class="level1">
    <label class="name" >name:</label> 
    <p>
      Text starting here - style #1 <br>
      text which should go in a new line with different style #2 <br>s
      text continue here with another new line - style #1
    </p>
    </div>
  </div>

<style type="text/css">
.line {
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 477px;
    margin: 0 auto;


}

.level1 {
    display: inline-flex;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 12px;


}

.name {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 40px;
    min-width: 50px;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 15px;


}

</style>
```

Comment: Still when I tag the second line in a <span> tag, It creates a new column for it instead of a new line.

Comment: use <br> tage to create a new line

Answer (score 0):

You basically want your elements to be aligned right, something like this should do it, you'll need to manage different screen sizes of course.

```css
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: 0;
}

.main {
  margin: 1px;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

section {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  text-align: right;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
}

section>.name {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

section>.content {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 5px;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <section>
    <div class="name"> name:</div>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Text starting here - style #1 </p>
      <p>text which should go in a new line with different style #2</p>
      <p>text continue here with another new line - style #1</p>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <div class="name">Longer name:</div>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Text starting here - style #1 </p>
      <p>text which should go in a new line with different style #2</p>
      <p>text continue here with another new line - style #1</p>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <div class="name">Much Longer name:</div>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Text starting here - style #1 </p>
      <p>text which should go in a new line with different style #2</p>
      <p>text continue here with another new line - style #1</p>
      <p>text continue here with another new line - style #1</p>
      <p>text continue here with another new line - style #1</p>
      <p>text continue here with another new line - style #1</p>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <div class="name">A really Longer name:</div>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Text starting here - style #1 </p>
      <p>text which should go in a new line with different style #2</p>
      <p>text continue here with another new line - style #1</p>
      <p>text continue here with another new line - style #1</p>
      <p>text continue here with another new line - style #1</p>
      <p>text continue here with another new line - style #1</p>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```